# how to read values from a price range slider(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( "#minValue" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
$( "#maxValue" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

How to read values when slider sliding ?

`minValue->minimum` value of slider when slider sliding

`maxValue->maximum` value of slider when slider sliding

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for PHP to read values whilst the slider is sliding. Javascript is a client side language, PHP is server side.

What you could do however, is get a slide to trigger an ajax call to a PHP page on the server. You would then use the response of this ajax request to modify parts of the page as necessary.